# Batch for Windows Registry

Tags: windows, windows-10, windows-registry, search

So I need to know if it's possible to create a batch file for this darn thing.

1. Create a new key in the following path named Explorer

HKEY_CURRENT_USER\SOFTWARE\Policies\Microsoft\Windows\

2. And on the right window create a new DWORD named DisableSearchBoxSuggestions with value data = 1

So the result should be like this:[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/E5EkC.jpg)

Thanks in advance and sorry for my bad english.

Comment: Sure it is. However, note that Super User is not a script writing service. We can help fix your script, but you must provide its source code.

Comment: Thanks, Daniel B. I was using this powershell line but at least for me only works for win10, and i'm using win11 so that's why i asked for help with an possible batch. But i  understand the reason of your post. if( -not (Test-Path -Path HKLM:\SOFTWARE\Policies\Microsoft\Windows\Explorer)){
New-Item HKLM:\SOFTWARE\Policies\Microsoft\Windows\Explorer
}
Set-ItemProperty -Path HKLM:\SOFTWARE\Policies\Microsoft\Windows\Explorer -Name "DisableSearchBoxSuggestions" -Value 1 -Type DWORD

Answer (score 0):

There is a tool called reg.exe that you can use to manipulate the registry from the command line:

```
@echo off
net session >nul 2>&1 || (powershell start -verb runas '"%~0"' &exit /b)
reg add "HKEY_CURRENT_USER\SOFTWARE\Policies\Microsoft\Windows" /v "DisableSearchBoxSuggestions" /d 1 /t reg_dword
```

Comment: Thanks mate.  I'll give a try. This thing is really making me nuts in win11